# Can I use Intermediate Value Theorem this way?

Tags: calculus, functions, interval-arithmetic

The question says:

> Prove that $f(x) = 3$ has a solution on the interval $[a,b]$

And Intermediate Value Theorem says that

> if $f(a) * f(b) < 0$, then it has a solution on that interval

So instead of seeing if $3$ is between the interval and stuff like that. Can't I just do this:

$$f(x) = 3$$
 $$f(x) - 3 = 0$$

And then we consider $f(x) - 3$ a completely new whole function called $g(x) = 0$

According to the theorem, I can say that since $g(a) * g(b) < 0$, it has a solution on the interval.

Can I do that?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Wait, are you sure? Because I did this on last week's exam, and the math teacher didn't consider the solution I have done correctly. It confused the hell out of me. I would be really glad if I knew that the solution I have done is correct so that she corrects the grade.

Comment: Of course you can, but keep in mind that $f$ (in this case your $g$) must be at least CONTINUOUS, otherwise the theorem doesn't hold.

Comment: @Maffred Definitely. Thanks.

Comment: When you "state" the Intermediate Value Theorem, who is the "it" that has a solution? Also, saying you have a "new whole function called $g(x)=0$," that isn't too good. You want to define a new function $g(x)$ and deduce that the *equation* $g(x)=0$ has a solution. My point is that your teacher is not happy with the way you're stating things, even though you have the right ideas in your mind. (I say this as someone who was a math professor for almost 40 years.)

Comment: @TedShifrin I didn't deduce anything. It's just that I thought I can define the whole f(x) - 3 as a function called g(x), since f(x) - 3 = 0 then I can also say that g(x) = 0, can't I?

Comment: Yes, defining $g(x)=f(x)-3$, you can say that the equation $f(x)=3$ has a solution, say $x=c$, if and only if the equation $g(x)=0$ has a solution (likewise, $x=c$). Presumably you knew something like $f(a)<3<f(b)$ which translated into $g(a)<0<g(b)$. Then, since $f$ is continuous, it follows that $g$ is continuous and meets the hypotheses of the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: @TedShifrin So is my solution correct or not??

Comment: I have given you lots of complaints and explained what needs to be said for it to be correct. If all you wrote down is what you've typed here, I would give at most half credit.

Comment: @TedShifrin I mean, it, of course, has to be continuous. It was just very obvious since it's a part of the theorem and I didn't need to say it all again. Besides, I think it's obvious that g(x) the new function is going to be continuous. Just saying. Thanks for the additions.

Comment: These things you're saying are "obvious" need to be explicitly written down if you expect credit on an exam. Your professor is not a mind-reader.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm talking about here. I don't think it's necessary to mention all the whole theorem all over again, I just focused on the actual main idea. Of course, I would mention all that you said in my exam paper. Again, thank you for your addition! I really found it very useful.

Comment: @TechnoKnight it is totally appropriate (encouraged?) to redact your questions here with details as in an exam.

Comment: It should be obvious that you haven't typed the full question. Given just the fact that $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ how can you conclude that $f(x) =3$ has a solution in $[a, b] $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. There is a variant of this argument which allows you to prove the Brouwer fixed point theorem in one dimension: suppose $f:[a,b]\to [a,b]$ is a continuous function. Show there exists a $c\in [a,b]$ with $f(c)=c$.

It's a great exercise to try out, and from your question you are halfway there already.